# allow only one checkbox to be checked in angular Material

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

***I am using Angular 6 and angular material data-table with checkbox I want to select one checkbox at one time.***

Mat checkbox I am using as a checkbox.

the only one can show selected checked and previous one unchecked.

```
<span *ngIf="key.data == 'check'">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row ; let i = index;">
       <mat-checkbox (click)="checkBoxSelected(row, i)"></mat-checkbox>
    </td>
</span>
```

***How to i hendle in typescipt so***

[image]

***If I selected Both it allows me to do***

[image]

***but i want to select only one at a time so if you have an idea or you want to idea what [check here](https://codepen.io/thompsonemerson/pen/jPvgoy) like ***

Comment: Can you please provide stackblitz with the issue!!!

Comment: i want something like this https://codepen.io/thompsonemerson/pen/jPvgoy

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried to accomplish the task?

Comment: i am just trying to do one checkbox selected at one and old more de- select

Comment: use a tool for what it's meant to - [Material radio buttons](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview)

Answer (score 0):

```
 For selecting only one checkbox at one time, you can make changes in your code like this: 

<tr *ngFor="let item of managerList;let i = index"> 
                            <td scope="row">
                             <div class="media align-items-center">
  <mat-checkbox [disabled]="isDisabled" [checked]="selected === i" (change)="selected 
  =i" id="{{item.id}}" #checkbox="matCheckbox"  (click)="getrecord(checkbox,element)"> {{item.fullName}} </mat-checkbox> 
</div>
 </td>
 </tr>
```